# Is it important what is store in date?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to know is it important what is store in my date column?

For example when my user come from `fa-IR` culture database store date.time.now() as `1395/05/25 10:20:30 ق.ض` butwhen my culture is `en-US` The data store as `10/08/2016` are there same as date or I must check culture and change the value?
I don't care what is want to store in database I load date as formated.

Is `1395/05/25 10:20:30 ق.ض` only in view and database store data as another data (2 digit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it is about important as whatever use it is getting in your queries.

If the column is popular in WHERE clauses for reporting, triggers, etc. then I'd say just make sure that you don't have to run a function or CAST/CONVERT on the column whenever it is used in a WHERE clause.  This is because running functions on an indexed column will cause the index to be ignored.

Comment: That means you tell me do not try to parse as string value first I get actual value then do anything with this real value. isn't it?

Comment: You should be storing the value in whatever way is necessary to not have to run it against a function when using it as part of popular queries.  For example: if you are constantly joining to a Fiscal Period table, and the table has "en-us" culture, then you should probably change one of the two to match.  Also consider: DATETIME and DATETIME2 data types.

Comment: Therefor if database store `01/18/2017` as `1395/10/29` and I send query `select * form table where date is '01/18/2017' ` the database return this row. Is it true?

Comment: SQL Server is usually smart enough to translate, but it may cause the execution plan to force a convert on your DATE column to match your string, which you don't want.  Solution: create a function that converts en-us to fa-IR, and then run SELECT * FROM table where date = ConvertDateFromenUStofaIR('01/18/2017')